# Is a 3/8" copper tube from the shut off valve to the copper tube that threads on the relief valve needed?

Tags: water, heater

The 3/8" copper tube runs from the shut off valve to the copper tube that threads on to the relief valve. Does the 3/8" copper tube need to be there? Because the 3/8" line all it’s doing is letting water flow out the pipe contacted to the relief valve.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the DIY site. Some photos and a better description of your application and what you are trying to achieve would go a long way toward getting an answer to your question.

Comment: Valve for what?

Comment: ask one of your friends to read your question .... ask if they understand what you are saying

Comment: Are we talking about a water heater?

Answer (score 0):

The pipe that releases water or steam connected to the relief valve must be big enough for a high throughput. From 100 milliliter water a high volume of ca. 160 liter steam is produced. This production can happen very fast in case of pressurized "overheated" water when the pressure is reduced by the opening valve.

Comment: I gotta say, this answer makes as much sense as the question...